# MapQuest API Details

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapquest

I am new to MapQuest. In my project i am using map to show the routes. In this I have used Mapquest Open javascript API. In that I have problem that API respond several routes and display each route and focus on the location. But each request of APi i am getting new Map overwrite the old. I need only one instance but the location need to change.

I have used this method to show a map.

```
MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function() {
                var options={
                    elt:document.getElementById('map_canvas'),        
                    zoom:12,                                   
                    latLng:{lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},    
                    mtype:'osm'                               
                };

                window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);
```

Each time i will call this method. how to solve this problem? I have created the global Instace for new MQA.TileMap(options) but no luck.